# Position:fixed в мобильных браузерах, как пофиксить?

Tags: html, css, position

Есть таблица, у которой при определенном разрешении первая колонка становится фиксированной, во всех остальных появляется внутренний, горизонтальный скролл (ясно, что решение не самое лучшее, но так в тз).
Position:fixed известная проблема. Находил решения с прилипающим хедером, но это маленько не то, что нужно мне.
Может кто знает рабочие решения?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Сложно понять что вам надо сделать. Скиньте линк на сайт или на codepen.

Comment: А в чём вопрос? :-/

Comment: держите http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKKNdR

Comment: Дак что не так и что надо. В примере левая колонка прилипает при определенном разрешении. В чем вопрос то.

Comment: Position: fixed на мобильных устройствах не работает - изветный факт, поэтому и интересуюсь каким образом можно все это дело закостылить. Откройте с мобильного устройства и посмотрите. Сделаю скрин еще и выложу.

Comment: проблема решена